# Creating View with dynamic columns by stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I'm stuck in implementing a stored procedure for generating a view with dynamically columns.
This view should represent following PIVOT SQL-Statement as shown here:

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/204da/4)

Why i am using a stored procedure with dynamic SQL?
The requirements are, to implement a database object, which behaves like shown statement working on MSSQL 2005 until now and also on Oracle starting with 9i (unfortunatelly...).
Now, because of missing deeper knowledge on how to implement in a better way, i decided to use a stored procedure.

But now im stuck and any suggestions are highly appreciated. Also any suggestion on how to implement in a better way but with the same result like shown SQL Fiddle Demo are welcome.

My SP currently looks like that:

```
create procedure GeneratePivotLeistungsbewertungen
as
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE cActivityNames CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT distinct ActivityName
    FROM Leistungsbewertungen

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @dyn_col_list NVARCHAR(MAX)

OPEN cActivityNames  
FETCH NEXT FROM cActivityNames INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       SET @dyn_col_list = @dyn_col_list + N'(select lb.Bewertungswert from Leistungsbewertungen lb where lb.ActivityName = '+ @name +' and lb.LeistungsId = o.LeistungsId)' + @name + ','

       FETCH NEXT FROM cActivityNames INTO @name  
END   
deallocate cActivityNames

select LEFT(@dyn_col_list, LEN(@dyn_col_list)-1)

DECLARE @execVar NVARCHAR(MAX) = N' VIEW dbo.PivotLeistungsbewertungen 
    AS
        SELECT max(o.LeistungsId) LeistungsId, max(o.Gnr) GOP,' + @dyn_col_list + 
         'FROM leistungen o group by o.LeistungsId'

SET @execVar = CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.PivotLeistungsbewertungen'))
THEN N'ALTER' ELSE N'CREATE' + @execVar END;

  BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql @execVar;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
  END CATCH  
go
```

Any ideas why it doesn't create the view if you call it like that:

```
USE [Q20133_0_NO]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GeneratePivotLeistungsbewertungen]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

**EDITED for Solutions (2005/2008R2)**

**Updated with working Stored Procedure (tested under SQLServer 2008 R2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GeneratePivotLeistungsbewertungen
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(32)
    DECLARE @dyn_col_list NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT @dyn_col_list = isnull(@dyn_col_list + ',', '') + N'(
              select lb.Bewertungswert
              from Leistungsbewertungen lb
              where
                  lb.ActivityName = ''' + ActivityName + ''' and
                  lb.LeistungsId = o.LeistungsId
        )' + ActivityName
    FROM Leistungsbewertungen
    GROUP BY ActivityName

    DECLARE @execVar NVARCHAR(MAX) = N' VIEW dbo.PivotLeistungsbewertungen 
        AS
            SELECT max(o.LeistungsId) LeistungsId, max(o.Gnr) GOP' + @dyn_col_list + ' FROM leistungen o group by o.LeistungsId'

    SET @execVar = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM sys.VIEWS
                    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.PivotLeistungsbewertungen')
                    )
                THEN N'ALTER' + @execVar
            ELSE N'CREATE' + @execVar
            END;

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_executesql @execVar;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
```

**For SQLServer 2005 it has to be following Implementation (also working with 2008 R2)**

```
DECLARE @execVar NVARCHAR(200) 
SET @execVar = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM sys.procedures
                    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.GeneratePivotLeistungsbewertungen')
                    )
                THEN N'DROP PROCEDURE GeneratePivotLeistungsbewertungen;'
            END;
EXEC(@execVar)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE GeneratePivotLeistungsbewertungen
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(32)
    DECLARE @dyn_col_list NVARCHAR(MAX) 

    SET @dyn_col_list = ''

    SELECT @dyn_col_list = isnull(@dyn_col_list + ',', '') + N'(
              select lb.Bewertungswert
              from Leistungsbewertungen lb
              where
                  lb.ActivityName = ''' + ActivityName + ''' and
                  lb.LeistungsId = o.LeistungsId
        ) AS ' + ActivityName
    FROM Leistungsbewertungen
    GROUP BY ActivityName
    ORDER BY MAX(Bewertungsschritt)

    DECLARE @execVar NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @execVar = N' VIEW dbo.PivotLeistungsbewertungenView
        AS
            SELECT max(o.LeistungsId) LeistungsId, max(o.Gnr) GOP' + @dyn_col_list + ' FROM leistungen o group by o.LeistungsId'

    SET @execVar = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM sys.VIEWS
                    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.PivotLeistungsbewertungenView')
                    )
                THEN N'ALTER' + @execVar
            ELSE N'CREATE' + @execVar
            END;

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_executesql @execVar;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost certain that you just have to initialize your `@dyn_col_list` and you'll be ok:

```
set @dyn_col_list = ''
```

before opening cursor. Anyway, if you have a problems like that, best way to fast check it is just to `print @execVar` before execute to be sure what exactly you're executing.

Also, I usually use this syntax instead of cursor:

```
select
    @dyn_col_list = isnull(@dyn_col_list + ',', '') +
    N'(
          select lb.Bewertungswert
          from Leistungsbewertungen lb
          where
              lb.ActivityName = '+ ActivityName +' and
              lb.LeistungsId = o.LeistungsId
    )' + ActivityName
from Leistungsbewertungen
group by ActivityName
```

It's shorter, automatically eliminates last comma and you don't need to initialize `@dyn_col_list` (well, in fact you have to NOT initialize it or initialize it with null if there some possibility that it could be not null)

Comment: ok, it makes sence to initialize the variable before assign it to itself. Thanks for that. One thing now, is it the right way to cut the last comma at the column list with <br><pre><code>select LEFT(@dyn_col_list, LEN(@dyn_col_list)-1)</code> Its telling me "wrong syntax near from statement". The last comma doesn't get cut off. <br> Or maybe there is a way to identify the last loop inside the while statment so to decide if i have to add a comma or not?

Comment: How do i implement your update inside my SP? If i simply copy paste it, i only get the last column of the result. That select will give n-possible results. (i never did something with MSSQL Sps before, i'm currently learning the syntax)

Comment: @Dom84 yeah, changed the answer, it was no completely correct