# How to dynamiclly call a table from inside a view by name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need write a sql view on series of tables in a database.  The problem is that the table only contains one month of history.  Each month a new table is created.  For example dbo.LOG_2015_09 would be September's table.

I need to write a view that shows me the last 60 days of history.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.LOG_2015_09
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbo.LOG_2015_08
```

The problem is that next month this will not be valid anymore.

I am limited to using SQL Views.  Stored procedures are not an option.

One thought I had was to create a Table Function to get the relevant tables but I don't think we can use dynamic SQL to generate the code.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:  This is a sample of the table definition created by the application.  I do not have any access to modify the table.  I can only create views or functions.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLOG201509](
   [LASTUPD] [datetime] NULL,
   [CREDATE] [datetime] NULL,
   [SERIALNO] [int] NOT NULL,
   [LSEQNO] [int] NOT NULL,
   [EVENTNO] [int] NOT NULL,
   [EVDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [LOGDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__CLOG2015__D08461DA672EF3E9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 ([SERIALNO] ASC,
  [EVENTNO] ASC,
  [LSEQNO] ASC
 ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

These tables contain over a million records each.

EDIT:  I have attempted to create a TABLE UDF to combine the tables but without being able to use Dynamic SQL I don't know how to make it change the tables based on the date.  I would want to have this months table and last months table joined together to reference.  The problem is that I have to go and remember to update this UDF each month and until I do, the data is unavailable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[KS_ManitouSync_OPT_CLOG]()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM CLOG201511
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *
    FROM CLOG201512
)
```

As a reminder I cannot use Stored Procs,  It must be useable by a program that supports a single SQL SELECT Query only.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Views are not a good option if you are trying to see your historical data. The view gets refreshed each time the base tables are updated. So, I think what you might need is some kind of audit log table to keep track of changes for past 60 days and truncate once it passes that period.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: It might make sense to create a table to hold the appropriate data and schedule a task to run each night to delete the oldest day's data and add the newest. It depends on the amount of data, how often it is queried, ... .

Comment: I cannot create a table as the data enters these tables in high volume and I do not have any access to the code.  And the amount of data in these tables numbers the millions of records.  IE(Last month's table had 1.7 million records.)

Comment: This is still unresolved, and ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a partitioned view which unions all the tables, but each table must have a constraint to limit the time interval allowed in it. In this case, when you select from the partitioned view, using a WHERE clause on the partitioning column, only the relevant tables will be accessed.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I don't have any access to change the tables and they are created automatically by the application.  I need to be able to query these tables for statistical reporting.  The amount of data in these tables numbers the millions of records. IE(Last month's table had 1.7 million records.)

Answer (score 1):

create your view via a stored procedure. there you can figure out which log tables are all existing and then build your create view command dynamicaly.

have a look in a quite similar question i had in the past:

[Creating View with dynamic columns by stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701866/creating-view-with-dynamic-columns-by-stored-procedure)

Comment: I have done this in the past but I need to call a view not a stored proc.  I have used a store proc to create the view but then I have to run that stored proc each time the view needs to be recreated.

Comment: maybe this could be setup in a server agent job, for example, which then calls the proc. But of course i don't have that deep knowledge of your implementation and situation so that is just a guess

Answer (score 0):

If really must use a view (you cannot use a stored procedure) and you cannot update the view automatically (using an SQL Server Agent job or using a DDL trigger), you could use dynamic SQL in a view using OPENROWSET, but there are a lot of caveats, see http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY